# Angular + MongoDB mongoose: Component not recognizing object property

Tags: mongodb, angular, mongoose

This is an excerpt from my product document defined in MLab:

```
 {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "596161e1734d1d25634366ce"
},
 "images": {
    "regular": [
        "Amana Electric Range in Stainless Steel-1.jpg",
        "Amana Electric Range in Stainless Steel-2.jpg",
        "Amana Electric Range in Stainless Steel-3.jpg",
        "Amana Electric Range in Stainless Steel-4.jpg",
        "Amana Electric Range in Stainless Steel-5.jpg"
    ]
   }
}
```

This is an excerpt of the corresponding model in Mongoose:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    images:{}
});

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema, 'product');
module.exports=Product;
```

This is my Product model in Angular:

```
export class Product {
_id: string;  
images:{};
}
```

I am able to display the image in my Angular template as shown below:

```
 <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img src="..\assets\images\{{product.images.regular[0]}}"
       id="largeimage" class="text-center">
  </div>
```

I try to access the same image in my component using the same construct as shown in the template above:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = params['id'];

  this.product = this.dataService.getProduct(id);

  this.mainImage = this.product.images.regular[0];
})
}
```

I get the error: property regular does not exist. The property regular does exist as demonstrated in the template but for some reason it doesn't work in the component. I believe it might have to do with my model definition: images{}. How do I properly model the images object in Mongoose and in my Angular model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mongoose schema is expecting an empty object. If you're looking for something similar to the `any` type in typescript you can use `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    images: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema, 'product');
module.exports = Product;
```

Also, in your product model in Angular it's best practice to explicitly state the type:

```
export class Product {
  _id: string;  
  images: any;
}
```

Comment: "images: any" worked like a charm. Thank you very much.